# how to add already compressed images to pdf... without changing nothing on the already quality (except maybe dpi), using imagemagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I have 100 webp images. I want to create a pdf.

In order to help imagemagick i do this from resource point of view (1st command it does one file per line than multiple ones):

```
find . -name '*.webp,.jpg'  -exec mogrify -quality 100 -format  tiff *.webp {} +
convert "*.{tiff}"   -quality 100 outfile.pdf
```

This results 400+mb pdf file. then I do:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
-sOutputFile="/mnt/jpgs/output_new.pdf" \
"/mnt/jpgs/output_original.pdf"
```

Which reduces pdf size to ~36mbs.

I know how gs works. I have read about it.
Which i cannot understand is how to produce "36mb" pdf from the scratch without using afterward gs conversion.

note that `pdfimages -list outfile.pdf` says

that original pdf has ratio ~120% per image while compressed pdf has a ratio of <~12%.

So it appears that compress the images (in what format with what options?).
Because even chosing "`-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer`" which says that corresponds to 300dpi,
both pdf files according to  `pdfimages -list outfile.pdf` says 70 dpi.

So my question is how to add already compressed images to pdf... without changing nothing on the already quality (except maybe dpi), using imagemagick?

Comment: Your `find` command looks extremely unlikely to be correct to me.  So does your `convert` command. Please use the proper SI unit (MB) for megabytes - unless you really mean millibits which seems unlikely. In answer to your question, **ImageMagick** is a *raster processor*, so it will always convert everything to a raster before doing anything, so you can't actually use it to add images to an existing PDF - if that's what you are asking.

Comment: my aim was to produce a pdf without decompressing/compressing images and loosing quality. i found img2pdf. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found what i was searching for:
(100 images = 22 mb imagemagick produced 400mb pdf file!!!)

From man page for img2pdf:

> Losslessly convert raster images to PDF without re-encoding PNG,
> JPEG, and JPEG2000 images. This leads to a lossless conversion of PNG,
> JPEG and JPEG2000 images
> with  the only added file size coming from the PDF container itself.  Other raster graphics formats are losslessly stored using the
> same encoding that PNG uses.    Since PDF does not support images with
> transparency and since img2pdf aims to never be lossy, input images
> with an alpha channel are not supported.
> The output is sent to standard output so that it can be redirected into a file or to another program as part of a shell pipe.
> To directly write the output into a file, use the -o or --output
> option.

For comparison:

- Imagemagick conversion images to pdf:~400mb - no artifacts 72dpi - 122% compression ratio
- gs compression of Imagemagick pdf:    ~40mb - some artifacts ~12% compression ratio
- img2pdf *.webp -o output_img1.pdf:   ~171mb - no artifacts  96dpi ~50% compression ratio
- gs compression of img2pdf pdf:        ~40mb - some artifacts ~12% compression ratio

So, I stayed with img2pdf original version of 171mb.